Angular app: Connect the base repo with the customer repos
I would like to make my Angular app scalable. I use nx and a nx workspace. Within the workspace I outsourced the base implementation (core) and the base implementation code for each customer in libraries.
I created two Git repositories, one for the base implementation (our core code) and one for the base implementation of the customer.
If a customer want to use the app, I just want to create a new customer repo based on the base implementation code for the customers, that I can adapt the code based on the customer wishes without changig our base implementation (core).
Furthermore, if I change code in our base implementation (core), I don't want to overwrite the customer's implementation (Customer Repo).
So there must be two repos. One for the customer and one for our core implementation (both are seperated). The problem I've experieced is, that the customer's implementation must be in the core implementation, because else the components and modules of the customer repo couldn't be found.
My question is: How can I implement this idea, without moving the customer's repo into the core repo?
